# Does anyone here use PHP-GTK? Is there a better alternative?

Tags: php-gtk

I had made some questions regarding PHP-GTK (there are only 4 `php-gtk` tagged questions and three are mine) and I end up answering myself because no one answer them.

I know it is a strange language selection but I was attracted to it because it runs on several OSs and the fact that I can reuse some of my code (also the apps end up looking good and I can make little installers in NSIS that just rocks).

Is there a better alternative, that is free (as in freedom) and can run on several platforms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both Python and Ruby can work with the GTK libraries. These may be better chocies of languages for you (you'll certainly get more folk here answering your questions :)

See [Is Ruby any good for GUI development?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115501/is-ruby-any-good-for-gui-development) and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115495/is-python-any-good-for-gui-development for links for Ruby and Python respectively.

Answer (score 2):

Does it have to be GPL, or are other open source solutions acceptable? Python has much more mature GTK integration and it's open source but not GPL. You can bundle python scripts into an executable with a runtime. You can generate these executables for many platforms including Windows.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the first part of your question. Yes - I use php-gtk. This could be the start of a beautiful friendship.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question from the other side.

Other GUI applications that can be coded in PHP include [wxWidgets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WxWidgets) and [Qt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_(software)), both of which have PHP bindings available: [wxPHP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WxPHP) and [PHP-Qt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP-Qt)